How do I keep from generating an Error when creating an Output Stream
I have found many examples of creating the output stream, and used them in my code. I am getting the following error: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.io.OutputStream
I cannot move into the next phase until I get past this. Any ideas would be appreciated.
Here is the class code:
import static com.codename1.ui.CN.*;
import com.codename1.components.ScaleImageLabel;
import com.codename1.system.Lifecycle;
import com.codename1.ui.*;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.*;
import com.codename1.io.*;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.*;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.io.InputStream;
import com.codename1.ui.CN.*;
import com.codename1.io.File;
import com.codename1.util.StringUtil;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class Plays {
    Form plays = new Form(new FlowLayout());
    ArrayList PlayList = new ArrayList();
    FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();

    public Plays() throws IOException {
            try {
                InputStream fis = fs.openInputStream("plays.txt");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(ex);
                Dialog.show("Touchline Assitant", "I cannot find the Plays List!", "OK", null);
            }
            String fileName = fs.getAppHomePath() + "plays.txt";
            try(Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(fileName)) {
                w.write( "Play List");
            }
            plays.show();
    }
}


There are several mistakes in the code. This line:
InputStream fis = fs.openInputStream("plays.txt");

Uses a relative path instead of an absolute path. It should be:
InputStream fis = fs.openInputStream(fileName);

But a better way would be:
if(fs.exists(fileName)) {
   ... load the file
}

To open the file stream you need to use the fs methods. Specifically:
new OutputStreamWriter(fs.openOutputStream(fileName))

